# Is there a way to avoid this repetition in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

what is the best way to write this function without repeting some values and only add the needed value **initialText**

```
createThread = () => {
    if (this.props.first) {
        publishLow = window.google.createPublish({
            readId : this.props.readId
        });
    } else {
        publishLow = window.google.createPublish({
            readId : this.props.readId,
            // The value needed in this condition
            initialText : this.props.initialText
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Personally I would leave it as it is. It makes it more readable and testable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can refactor this way, to avoid the repetition

```
createThread = () => {
    const { readId, first, initialText } = this.props;
    const payload = { readId };
    if (!first) payload.initialText = initialText;
    publishLow = window.google.createPublish(payload);
}
```

Also added object deconstruction to make code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andy but if you would want to make it smaller here is my idea:

```
createThread = () => {
    const arg = {
            readId : this.props.readId
    };
    if (!this.props.first) {
        arg["initialText"] = this.props.initialText;
    }

    publishLow = window.google.createPublish(arg);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
createThread = () => {
  const { readId, first, initialText } = this.props;
  const payload = first ?  { readId } : { readId , initialText };
  publishLow = window.google.createPublish(payload);
}
```